# XML to PDF in an ASHX Handler (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, pdf, webforms

I appear to be stuck a bit.

I have a class for content exporting to Excel, which has been working just fine. The issue is though, now we need PDF files for the same data as well. It would be amazingly helpful and time saving if there was a way to convert raw xml into a readable pdf file. I'm currently displaying the xml in an ashx handler, although I have no idea what to do with the data.

Example XML input:

```
    <?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<Styles>
<Style ss:ID="linkStyle">
<Font ss:Color="#0000FF" ss:Underline="Single"/>
</Style>
<Style ss:ID="s831920757">
<Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Center" ss:Rotate="0" ss:WrapText="1"/>
<Font ss:FontName="Arial" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="10" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="0" ss:Italic="0"/>
<Interior ss:Color="#C4D79B" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
<Borders>
<Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1" ss:Color="#aaaaaa"/>
<Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1" ss:Color="#aaaaaa"/>
<Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1" ss:Color="#aaaaaa"/>
<Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1" ss:Color="#aaaaaa"/>
</Borders>
</Style>
<Style ss:ID="s560423649">
<Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Center" ss:Rotate="0" ss:WrapText="1"/>
<Font ss:FontName="Arial" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="10" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="0" ss:Italic="0"/>
</Style>
<Style ss:ID="s305706785">
<Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Center" ss:Rotate="0" ss:WrapText="1"/>
<Font ss:FontName="Arial" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="10" ss:Color="#ffffff" ss:Bold="1" ss:Italic="0"/>
<Interior ss:Color="#777777" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
</Style>
<Style ss:ID="s-2114824811">
<Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Center" ss:Rotate="0" ss:WrapText="1"/>
<Font ss:FontName="Arial" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="10" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="0" ss:Italic="0"/>
<Interior ss:Color="#DDDDDD" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
<Borders>
<Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1" ss:Color="#aaaaaa"/>
<Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1" ss:Color="#aaaaaa"/>
<Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1" ss:Color="#aaaaaa"/>
<Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1" ss:Color="#aaaaaa"/>
</Borders>
</Style>
<Style ss:ID="s-475410841">
<Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Center" ss:Rotate="0" ss:WrapText="1"/>
<Font ss:FontName="Arial" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="10" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="0" ss:Italic="0"/>
</Style>
</Styles>
<Names/>
<Worksheet ss:Name="Summary">
<Table DefaultColumnWidth="400">
<Row>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s305706785" ss:MergeAcross="1">
<Data ss:Type="String">Header data</Data>
</Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
```